# ExtJS bad grid rendering on MVC build by sencha command

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I've built an MVC test application by sencha command, then I've built package: everything has been ok.

Then I've added a grid panel but rendering has been wrong: white headers, no row/column lines, no popup from headers, no possibility to select rows.

I've solved the problem by replacing MyApp\build\production\MyApp\resources with ext-4.2.1.883\resources\ext-theme-classic and renaming ext-theme-classic-all.css with MyApp-all.css.

It seems that my previous resource folder has been incomplete.

My solution seems to me "dirty". Anybody can suggest me a better solution or explain me why sencha command created an incomplete resource folder?

Best regards

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new class to the app the minimum you need to execute is:

```
sencha app refresh
sencha ant sass
```

Of course, rebuilding the app always works as the above does not copy the resources you may have added. To be 100% sure execute:

```
sencha app build
```

after you add a new class/file/resource.